# Ngrx/effects: how to show a dialog before updating via http

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-material, ngrx, ngrx-effects

I'm trying to update an item, but only if a dialog is confirmed. I think it's the right way to manage this via an ngrx effect.

I have an action, updateItem, which receives an item id:

```js
export const updateItem = createAction('...', props<{ id: number }>());
```

In my component I dispatch the action with an ID.

My effect looks like this:

```js
...
updateItem$ = createEffect(() => 
  ofType(ItemActions.updateItem),
  exhaustMap(({id}) => // <-- here i have access to the item id
    this.dialog.open<..., ..., boolean>(...).afterClosed()
  ),
  map(result => result ? result : new ActionItems.DialogClose()),
  switchMap(() => // <-- no access to id, since the result is now a boolean
    // make a http request to update user with id
    this.http.patch<...>(..., [...]).pipe(
      map(...),
      catchError(...)
    );
  )
);
...
```

Now, I have no access to the id, when I make the http call. How do I show the confirmation dialog, but keep the id? I thought about the "withLatestFrom"-operator, but I only want the http request to happen, if the dialog succeeds.

I also tried to create to different actions, one that dispatches the dialog and the second to dispatch updateItem, if the dialog succeeds. But even then, I'm missing the id since it's transformed.

I could pass the id to the dialog and return the id as a close result, but I actually want to keep my component presentational. 
Ngrx/platform example does something similar, but they don't need data(https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/master/projects/example-app/src/app/auth/effects/auth.effects.ts).

Does anyone have an idea on how I could solve this problem?

Comment: you are dispatching the action on button click ? can you share your component code?

Comment: As of this example, I just call this.store.dispatch(ActionItems.updateItem({id: id})). The currently working code uses the same approach as you desribed below

Comment: oh, I didn't know you have solved it already. If I  knew I would not invested that time :( .
but +1 for you success.

Answer (score 0):

From your description, what i understand is when user click a button to update an item, you want to show a dialog first and if the user confirms, you will send a http request to server to update the value. Assuming this is the case, I am giving the answer here.

If I had to do this, I would open that dialog in component.ts and call that action to make http call if the user confirm that dialog. You also can do something like this and it is more cleaner.

update your component.ts,

```
updateItem(id: number) {
    this.dialog.open <..., ..., boolean > (...)
    .afterClosed()
    subscribe((confirmed) => {
        if (confirmed) {
            // dispatch your action from here
            this.store.dispatch(updateItem({ id: id }))
        }
    }
}
```

change your effect to something like this.

```
updateItem$ = createEffect(() => 
  ofType(ItemActions.updateItem),
  map(action => action.id),
  switchMap((id: number) => // you should get your id here to make http call
    this.http.patch<...>(..., [...]).pipe(
      map(...),
      catchError(...)
    );
  )
);
```

Comment: This is what I'm actually doing right now and it works. But according to some sources, it would be good to handle service based stuff inside the effect. Like for example here (https://timdeschryver.dev/blog/start-using-ngrx-effects-for-this#2-handling-the-flow-of-a-angular-material-dialog) or in the example of the ngrx main repo (link in the post).

Comment: here, the author proposed it is possible to open dialog in effects. you also can do that and return another action to make http call. he prefers it in that way. but here you were trying to open a dialog and make http call in the same action/ effect. But this should be separated.